# Lock windows 10 audio output to single program

Tags: windows-10, audio

Is there a way to lock audio output to a single program on Windows 10? Essentially what I'm going to do is play some music during a theatre play from my laptop and would like to make sure no other sounds can be played (notifications and whatnot). I know I can disable Windows notifications, but I guess that does not eliminate all possible sources of sound.

EDIT: I could use the AudioRouter program to output audio to a null device and set the playback program to play on speakers, but how do I create a null audio device?

Comment: You don't need a null device, just "another" device that's the default. Assuming your other program allows you to switch the device or is "sticky". E.g. let everything play on your, not connected, Nvidia HDMI output and for the few select applications set the output device to whatever works.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. Feels a bit hacky, though. There should be a solution where I don't need an unconnected device.

Comment: A null device really isn't much different. You could also use a virtual audio cable which serves the same purpose.